# SHACL sh:rule with sh:condition in SPARQL in Topbraid Composer

Tags: sparql, rules, inference, shacl

The example ontology has two classes (`:MyClass` and `:Value`) and two properties (`:MyObjProp` and `:MyDataProp`).

```
:MyClass
  a owl:Class ;
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;
.
:MyDataProp
  a owl:DatatypeProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :MyClass ;
  rdfs:range xsd:string ;
.
:MyObjProp
  a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :MyClass ;
  rdfs:range :Value ;
.
:Value
  a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;
.
```

Some instances were added.

```
:MyClass_1
  a :MyClass ;
  :MyDataProp :Value_1 ;
  :MyObjProp :Value_1 ;
.
:MyClass_2
  a :MyClass ;
  :MyObjProp :Value_2 ;
.
:Value_1
  a :Value ;
.
:Value_2
  a :Value ;
.
```

A NodeShape `:NodeShapeRule` with a `sh:rule` (`:SPARQLRule_1`) was created. This rule creates new triples. With the `sh:condition` the rule should be restricted to a subset of targets.

```
:NodeShapeRule
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:rule :SPARQLRule_1 ;
  sh:targetClass :MyClass ;
.
:SPARQLRule_1
  a sh:SPARQLRule ;
  sh:condition :NodeShapeConditionSPARQL ;
  sh:construct """
    PREFIX : <http://example.org/ex#>
    CONSTRUCT
    {
        $this :MyDataProp \"New input\" .
    }
    WHERE
    {
        $this :MyObjProp ?p .
    }
    """ ;
.
```

For the restriction two equivalent NodeShapes were defined. The first constraint works with sh:property, the other uses sh:sparql.

```
:NodeShapeConditionProperty
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property [
      sh:path :MyObjProp ;
      sh:description "NodeShapeConditionProperty" ;
      sh:hasValue :Value_1 ;
    ] ;
  sh:targetClass :MyClass ;
.
:NodeShapeConditionSPARQL
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:sparql [
      sh:message "NodeShapeConditionSPARQL" ;
      sh:prefixes <http://example.org/ex> ;
      sh:select """
        PREFIX : <http://example.org/ex#>
        SELECT $this
        WHERE
        {
            $this :MyObjProp ?prop .
        }
        """ ;
    ] ;
  sh:targetClass :MyClass ;
.
```

While doing inferencing with Topbraid Composer I received different results for both solutions. Only the solution with sh:property provides the expected response. Please, can someone explain me this behavior?

```
:MyClass_1 :MyDataProp "New input"
```

Comment: Does http://example.org/ex correctly declare the default prefix? (Such questions are better handled at a platform that allows attachment of the full file. So the topbraid-users mailing list is an alternative).

Comment: Yes, the default prefix is declared correctly.

Comment: Since we have resolved this elsewhere, would you close or delete this item here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right explanation is that the SPAQRL query produces a constraint violation for each result (row) in SELECT query. So if the SPARQL query returns no result (rows) then all is fine and the rule will fire. The reason for this design is that this enables SPARQL queries to return more information about the violation, e.g. the focus node (`$this`) and the value node (`?value`).

Changing the `:NodeShapeConditionSPARQL` it produces violation for not existing results and then both solutions behave in the same manner.

```
:NodeShapeConditionSPARQL
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:sparql [
      sh:message "NodeShapeConditionSPARQL" ;
      sh:prefixes <http://example.org/ex> ;
      sh:select """
        PREFIX : <http://example.org/ex#>
        SELECT $this
        WHERE
        {
            FILTER NOT EXISTS { $this :MyObjProp ?anyProp } .
        }
        """ ;
    ] ;
  sh:targetClass :MyClass ;
.
```